# Thermostat Relay Positioning

Tags: thermostat

A Florida **AC-only** storage building is equally divided sections each with:

- a single hallway to provide access to storage units
- 3 doors (25 feet apart) provide building access into one of the hallways
- each section is designed the same as the others
- an AC handler is mounted in the hallway ceiling near the door and a thermostat

The design includes an electronic controller (one single-board computer and [electronic relays](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=8%20channel%20relay%20raspberry%20pi&crid=2HUHS5AA7249I&sprefix=8%20Channel%20relay%20rasp%2Caps%2C156&ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_20)) to signal for:

1. cooling (Yellow wire)
2. fan (Green wire).

## Decision point: The relays can be placed either:

- proximal to the computer: requiring thermostat wiring to be run to the computer
- proximal to the each air handler: requiring wiring to be run between air handler and the computer

What are the questions & considerations that must be thought-out before making a decision as to where to locate the relays?

[image]

Comment: I don't know what "rPI -relay wiring" is.  What voltage is it?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Wiring between the rPi computer and the relay is low (5V) voltage.  Thermostat wiring is 24V.  Question amended to remove reference to rPi (Raspberry Pi).

Comment: Is the computer being powered from a power supply on a separate 120V feed, or from power generated from the HVAC 24VAC system?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel:  A 5V-DC Raspberry Pi computer can be powered by either the [24V-AC](https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-12V-24V-AC-24V-To-DC-5V-4A-Output-Car-Buck-Power-Converter-Module-Waterproof/391294999737) or a separate 120-240V feed: that decision has yet to be made.  Each of the 3 Air-Handlers have a 24V line for a thermostat.  I suspect that each handler runs off [240V](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14601), if not 120V.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you don't want to do.

> Try to haul 5 volts any appreciable distance.

So I would lean seriously toward having the 24VAC wiring do the long haul.

However, if you want the gory details, you need to examine each option: determine the *current* that will flow on the long haul, and grind that through a voltage drop calculator given the expected wire size and distance.

The root of the problem is that a 0.5-volt drop only reduces 24V only 2%, but reduces 5 volts 10%.  Much worse, to do the same practical work, 5V needs *five times the current*, so 
now you're looking at 2% *versus 50%*.  In other words, voltage drop's practical burden is a function of voltage difference *squared*, *so it is 25 times worse for 5V than 24V*.